# How to look at Google Analytics data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I implemented Google Analytics in my Firebase web app following this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web). And then I set some events. But where can we read the resulting data?

If I look in the Firebase console, Analytics, StreamView;
I only see data for the last 30 minutes. I want to have a look over the last day or the last few days.

Comment: You should see all the data in Firebase UI after 24 hours, just to be sure try to filter by your app/stream.

Comment: Indeed it looks better now. Thanks.